# Check if an integer from a tuple is between the values of another tuple

Tags: python, logic

```
def are_values_crossed(tuple_1, tuple_2):
    if tuple_2[0] <= tuple_1[0] <= tuple_2[1]: return True
    if tuple_2[0] <= tuple_1[1] <= tuple_2[1]: return True
    if tuple_1[0] <= tuple_2[0] <= tuple_1[1]: return True
    if tuple_1[0] <= tuple_2[1] <= tuple_1[1]: return True
    return False

tuple_1 = (5, 17)
tuple_2 = (4, 13)
print(are_values_crossed(tuple_1, tuple_2))
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it? (without importing library if possible? In 1 line?)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply set intersection (since all your current conditions implicitly reflect `OR`-disjuncted clauses):

```
t_1 = (5, 17)
t_2 = (4, 13)
values_crossed = bool(set(t_1) & set(range(*t_2)) or set(t_2) & set(range(*t_1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an oneliner, but probably not optimal

```
if [x for x in range(tuple_1[0], tuple_1[1] + 1) if x in [y for y in range(tuple_2[0], tuple_2[1] + 1)]]:
    print('Are Value Crossed')
else:
    print('Are NOT Value Crossed)
```

This only works if the tuple contents are integers